# A polynomial with integral coefficients that is divided by squares of finite set of primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, chinese-remainder-theorem

I am reading the following writing by Keith Conrad: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ugradnumthy/crt.pdf

> [image]

I don't understand the remark 4.15. Where is the error in the following proof:

1) For every $i$ find an integer $a_i$ such that $f(a_i)\not\equiv 0 \pmod{p_i^2}$

2) Use the Chinese remainder theorem to find integer $a$ such that $\forall i \quad a\equiv a_i \pmod{p_i^2}$

3) $\forall i \quad f(a) \equiv f(a_i) \pmod{p_i^2} $, because $(x-y) |(f(x)-f(y))$ if $f$ is polynomial with integer coefficients.

4) $\forall i \quad f(a) \equiv f(a_i) \not\equiv 0 \pmod{p_i^2} $, contradiction.

Comment: I cannot see either why this analogue proof should not work.

Comment: 3 uses polynomial remainder theorem. not quite sure but something might mess up there ?

Comment: I don't know anymore what I was thinking when I wrote that remark that you were reading.  It's now been fixed.